# API google maps

Tags: html, div, google-api

estoy tratando de insertar un mapa en mi página web pero no me muestra nada, el código es en siguiente:

```
       <script
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD5dm4vRup7f9yAAeCaUY-2POKihj84B8c&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
  async
></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes especificar las coordenadas de la siguiente manera en un iframe con indica en [Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/embedding-map)

```
 <iframe
  width="450"
  height="250"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
  ?key=IzaSyD5dm4vRup7f9yAAeCaUY-2POKihj84B8c
  &location=46.414382,10.013988
  &avoid=tolls|highways" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
```

Comment: lo tengo para que se muestre en un div pero no me muestra absolutamente nada <div id="showMap" style="width: 1500px; height: 650px;">

Comment: Verifica la consola de tu navegador, talvez algún error te esta marcando ahi, tu codigo javascript debe estar así mas o menos no? 

`código`

 initMap()
 function initMap() {
   const myLatLng = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };
   const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("showMap"), {
     zoom: 4,
     center: myLatLng,
   });
   new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map,
     title: "Hello World!",
   });
 }
`código`